# Marketing Cloud - Wait Activity - Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have created an Automation and Journey Builder Customer Journey.

What I want to happen is 3 days before a Due Date I would like to send a reminder to the customer.

Daily at 7:55 Automation Studio populates a data extension with up to date data from Salesforce. The Due Date field is included in this data extension and the Journey has the automation as the entry audience.

At the first wait activity, by attribute (no end time set), the email is not sending to the related Contact.

- Today's Date = Date Automation Studio Runs 4/10/2017
- Due Date = 07/10/2017 (also tried with 08/10/2017)

What should I be aware of when using Automation Studio and a Wait activity together? Has anyone else had issues with wait activities not sending?

Comment: I have recreated the Journey. Issue was with the SQL query that did not include dates that would be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this exact issue, but the way I resolve a similar issue was by:

- Create a report in salesforce with 
  Due Date = NEXT 3 DAYS
  (This gives me the data to send to today)
- I then run an import into MC with an overwrite on the data extension and schedule the email send in automation studio

Comment: It looks like there was something in the attribute to attribute comparison that was causing an issue. This is now sorted and I will work on the second version.